# Unable to open URL in chrome

Tags: jmeter, selenium-chromedriver

I am using JMeter 5.3 and installed plugin manager 1.6.
Using plugin manager, I have installed selenium WebDriver.

[image: In lib folder]

[image: In ext folder]

Then downloaded latest chrome driver for Chrome 87 and gave .exe path in chrome driver config.

[image]

When I run this Chrome opens and then closes without opening URL and an error is thrown with **Response code:500**.

When I tried with latest Firefox driver, same error is thrown.

Not sure what is the issue.
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't use `beanshell` as the language, choose `groovy` from the "Script Language" drop-down and your code should start working:

[image]

[Since JMeter 3.1 users are recommended to use Groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) as the scripting language because:

1. It has better performance comparing to Beanshell
2. It's more Java-compliant including modern language features (generics, lambdas, etc.) while with Beanshell you're stuck at Java 1.5 level
3. It provides a lot of enhancements on top of Java SDK so you can do more in less lines of code

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)